# Can not access file in ipfs

Tags: ipfs

In my ubuntu 18.04 ipfs desktop client i have uploaded a file. But can not access the file with link, which i obtained from `Share link` option.

[image]

Here is my [shareable link](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZfsFFTa2sT35X5HUng9p8fPFH6svHPfXRvtXMzXQzd6z?filename=new%20file.txt).

I can not access the other file too, [link.](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmSQTgg6jtWqQTMh271YrrNpc9iGzZTLSaVipAoVEhb2oo?filename=index-t.html)

why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep a file available in the Peer2Peer IPFS system the file mus have been [pinned](https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/pin-files/). Remember to pin the files you want to keep available even when your computer is not Peering the file and for longer times.

---

I'm new to IPFS and found your Stack Overflow question when trying to figure out how to solve the same problem. In my experience I had uploaded a File in the IPFS and it had been reachable over the share link for a period of time until today when it wasn't.

So, after some research I got it working again when I pinned the file. This [Medium article](https://medium.com/@JohnZettler/how-to-save-a-file-on-ipfs-a-7-step-primer-3476469536c7) was a good read. In the screenshot you provided I can see that only one of the files are pinned, not the one you shared the link to. Most likely the problem will be fixed after you pinned it. This can be done through the client or Terminal commands (see the medium article to learn more about those).

Best of luck!

Comment: Actually it wasn't accessible even when it was pinned!!! I pinned and unpinned several times, uploaded and deleted, still no luck and then questioned here. And as you can see `index-t.html` is pinned in the image

Comment: It can take some time for things to propagate in the network, so it's important to keep pinned and also make sure the IPFS client is online and peering. ^^ It could be a good idea to add that follow-up info to your original question by editing it. More relevant info to a problem is always good to keep updated in the original question :)