# ipfs - I just cannot get it working reliably

Tags: ipfs

I'm new to IPFS.

I've installed the desktop client (MacOSX - Version 0.31.0 (0.31.0)) and imported files and I can see them in files.  I copy the Share URL for one and paste in to a browser and it tries for a long time and then Gateway timeout.  I leave it hours and try again but same problem.

I install the `ipfs cli` with `brew`.

The daemon is running since if i try and start the daemon in the CLI it fails with `lock file exists`.

Ok that sucks.  Let me try some other things.

Now in the CLI I can list those files:

```
▶ ipfs files ls
2019-03 VanCouver Head.jpg
2022-09 Boo - Father’s Day card.pdf
```

I can stat a file:

```
▶ ipfs files stat "/2019-03 VanCouver Head.jpg"
QmcrNkR5jtKDq7JoEQtTHQ25s5eMCfvPTtkg9djZHYMTdW
Size: 339651
CumulativeSize: 339783
ChildBlocks: 2
Type: file
```

Again entering `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcrNkR5jtKDq7JoEQtTHQ25s5eMCfvPTtkg9djZHYMTdW?filename=2019-03%20VanCouver%20Head.jpg` gives same error.

Ok try something else:

```
▶ ipfs add 2023-01-07\ Indian.pdf
added QmX4rMiAFQq2E5KJfZWnXnUU8M72WDj2YmJYu4KqYnGgFD 2023-01-07 Indian.pdf
 136.07 KiB / 136.07 KiB [=========================================================================================================] 100.00%

~/tmp/receipts
▶ ipfs files ls
2019-03 VanCouver Head.jpg
2022-09 Boo - Father’s Day card.pdf
```

So file not being added in CLI.

The desktop `status` isn't showing any errors.  And `ipfs swarm peers` looks to be ok:

```
▶ ipfs swarm peers
/ip4/108.62.0.103/udp/4001/quic-v1/p2p/12D3KooWJahwQCo4WW5GCZTqDKPpdXEDEiRxPToVVcaXyBbEkWzV
/ip4/120.226.39.192/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWHJbyskaXBypYwE7PrgYNDMtqN8pATDQfLdHXCuEPUxHm
/ip4/120.226.39.246/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWLcck3DE33chSgEUdrSKB7UUWt3uayStL6gcVww7eDxSo
/ip4/147.28.182.101/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWLw82DUKijnx5aAbA7bBdzV18o7qKHBtVdwtee5TPxQ7A
/ip4/35.161.110.72/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWS1ehpyirKUJma8tkVaMennGTCG9E822CXuWXnJ37YBqL
/ip4/45.76.55.81/udp/4001/quic-v1/p2p/12D3KooWRnuieBB7PZ6CrzgireoEu2DzzqBLULtGvJwvfpyqjZBL
```

So seems to be operating correctly.

No one seems to report such problems so the problem is my end.  But I've no idea why - I'd appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Thanks!

---

More information:

- I have confirmed that the firewall is allowing incoming connections for the IPFS Desktop and CLI.
- I understand about the pinning service (eg. [Can not access file in ipfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596321/can-not-access-file-in-ipfs)) and that it is just about garbage collection.  The Vancouver Head file is pinned but regardless GC would not touch this file yet given my node is running.
- I read at https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/lifecycle/#_1-content-addressable-representation that advertising happens (only) every 12 hours.  So maybe in another 6 hours or so the problem of not being able to see the file using shared links will be solved.

Comment: I believe i need to follow https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/nat-configuration/ but haven't done so yet.  For my purposes I'm using https://web3.storage.

Comment: Oh, as per https://check.ipfs.network/ that I found in https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/diagnostic-tools/?utm_source=bifrost&utm_medium=ipfsio&utm_campaign=error_pages, `ipfs swarm peers --direction` tells me all my connections are outbound.